# How to include a Photo Sphere in Contao 2?

Tags: javascript, contao, photosphere

I'm trying to embed kennydude's JavaScript Photo Sphere viewer (https://github.com/kennydude/photosphere) into a Contao CMS 2.11-based web site. I'm basically using the following code from his test.html which I adapted for the specific site:

```
<a href="http://www.***.tld/tl_files/labor/scripts/pano1.jpg" id="goForIt">Berechnen</a>
<div id="sphere" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
<script src="http://www.***.tld/tl_files/labor/scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.***.tld/tl_files/labor/scripts/sphere.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("goForIt").onclick = function(){
    sphere = new Photosphere(this.getAttribute("href"));
    sphere.loadPhotosphere(document.getElementById("sphere"));
    return false;
    };
</script>
```

I pasted that code into a .tpl file which has been uploaded to my templates folder and I'm embedding it via `{{file:code.tpl}` in a "custom HTML" content element.

However, it doesn't work - the link is visible in the frontend page, but it doesn't make the Photo Sphere load - however, it just redirects me to the sphere's JPG file.

How can I properly embed the sphere in my Contao frontend page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This quesion **is not related** with [tag:contao]. Do you understand javascript ?

Comment: In general, I do... do you mean that there's a mistake in the script?

Comment: I thought that the problem could be related to me embedding the script in the wrong way, making Contao's security system blocking it from being loaded.

Comment: I recommend you to use Contao 3. You can define custom header scripts in a layout.